# Moving my mods to the Steam version of Fallout 3

Tags: steam, mods, fallout-3

I've been playing Fallout 3 on and off for since it came out. I saw that the GOTY edition was on sale for $5 on Steam, so I figured I'd buy it for the DLC and fact I wouldn't need the CD anymore. Now, how do I set it up to use all my mods? Can I just copy my game directory over the Steam one, or do I have to install them one at a time with the Fallout Mod Manager? Can I copy my Steam version into the old Fallout 3 version, so that it isn't in Program Files (Which caused me problems last time)?

Is there anything else I should do to it before starting playing? I recall something about the DLC files being somewhere stupid, so you should move them when using mods; Is this still true with the GOTY edition sold through steam?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For as far as I know the only thing that mods do is add files to the 'data' folder within the Fallout installation folder and add their respective '.esp' files in the actual instlallation folder. So copying the 'data' folder and '.esp' files from the non-steam installation to the steam installation should work just fine. Do remember to make sure to select the mods on first launch though.